# Component does not see global styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

Component from globalstyle

Global styles are visible only in this component, col-lg-2,col-md-4 -> globalstyle

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './containers/App'
import './basestyle/flexboxgrid.min.css' //Global style

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
     <BrowserRouter>
       <App/>
     </BrowserRouter>
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

Component that should get styles

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from './Header.css'
import icon from './icon.png'


const Header = () => (
  <div className="row">
    <div className={`col-lg-2 col-md-4 ${styles.test}`} > //Here is not available
       <Link to="/категории">
         <div className={styles.logoBox}>
           <img src={icon} alt="logo"/>
             <h1>Белый кот</h1>
         </div>
       </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Header;
```

Webpack.config https://github.com/minaev-git/TestQuestion

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using css modules that change class names in your imported css file.

Comment: Possible,But how to fix it?

Comment: Since you're using postcss, wrapping all code in `'./basestyle/flexboxgrid.min.css'` with `:global { }` might help

Comment: Do I have to wrap all the selectors?

Comment: If you want all of them to be global, yeah: `:global { /* content of the file */ }` css-next nesting should do the trick

Comment: thx,i used precss,please add answer marzelin

Comment: I'm glad I could help but it's you who solved the problem. Congrats :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding global to your class name.
Eg

`:global(.yourClass) {
     //your css
}`

Answer (score 0):

Those styles will only be loaded if `<Header />` appears somewhere in `<App />`. I'm assuming that's the case, but otherwise make sure that the header component shows up in `<App />`. If that's not working, try looking around your `Network` tab of the web inspector and reload the page -- see if your CSS is even being loaded.

EDIT: Just seeing where in the code your class isn't working. If `.test` is a class in your global styles file, it wouldn't show up in the `Header.css` file. Try removing "styles" and just give it a class of `test` if `test` is a class in `flexboxgrid.min.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Import for CSS is

```
import './Header.css'
```

Reference the css classes in your component then with:

```
 <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-4 test" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to import bootstrap to your index.jsx, currently you are only importing this, require('./basestyle/flexboxgrid.min.css') that is not enough, how will your system know that there is boostrap if its not imported